# How to solve this problem of inaccurate modulus operators javascript?

Tags: javascript, modulus

Is there a way to solve this problem? I have tried it on a console and the results are wrong, but technically the results are correct

Experiment on the console:
[image]

Comment: JavaScript has issues with decimal calculations. The best way to avoid this, is to always use integers. Multiplying both numbers to attain suitable integer equivalent values would mean the calculations yield the correct result.

Comment: The problem being that `1 % 0.01 != 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In C and C++, the remainder operator accepts only integral operands;
>   in ECMAScript, it also accepts floating-point operands.
>   [ECMA Standands](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-applying-the-mod-operator)

The result of a floating-point remainder operation as computed by the % operator is not the same as the “remainder”
operation defined by IEEE 754-2008.

> The IEEE 754-2008 “remainder” operation computes the remainder from a
>   rounding division, not a truncating division, and so its behaviour is
>   not analogous to that of the usual integer remainder operator.

```
console.log(Math.floor(1%0.01)===0)
```

Instead the ECMAScript language defines % on floating-point operations to behave in a manner
analogous to that of the Java integer remainder operator; this may be compared with the C library function fmod.

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.floor()

```js
console.log(Math.floor(1%0.01)===0)
```